# C++,Strategy to use base class pointer storing subclasses and use the derived classes' method

Tags: c++, inheritance

The base class is the base of every classes in the program, which provides the x_pos and y_pos.

<del>Animal</del>(deleted for clearity) and Person are direct child classes of Base. 
Different people and animals may be created as sub-classes of Animal and Person
In my example, I created Wang class.

I have the following classes.

```
#include <iostream>
class Base{ 
protected:    
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
public:
    Base(int x,int y): x_pos(x), y_pos(y){};
    virtual ~Base(){};
    int getX(){return x_pos;};
    int getY(){return y_pos;};
};

class Person : public Base{
protected:
    char sex;
public:
    Person(int x,int y,char sex):Base(x,y), sex(sex){};
    virtual ~Person(){};
    char getSex(){return sex;};
    virtual void haveFun() = 0;
};

class Wang : public Person{
public:
    Wang(int x,int y,char a): Person(x,y,a){};
    ~Wang(){};
    void haveFun(){ std::cout << "Wang is coding" << std::endl;};
};
```

The question is that, for some reason, I must have a Base pointer to store the person or the animal.(For example, a floor has a "Base" that steps on it)

```
class Floor{
    Base *bs;
public:
    void haveFun(){ 
      // bs->Wang::havefun();
      // I want to achieve this goal
    }
}
```

How can I get access to the methods on Person/Animal and Wang level without down casting
Is there any strategy that I can apply here?
(I kind of think vistor's pattern may be applied here but I cant figure out how)

Comment: Still has compilation errors.

Comment: @PaulEvans corrected. Thanks

Comment: You are using inheritance inappropriately.  To illustrate .... Since when is "Wang" a different class of person?   The relationship between Cat and Animal is obvious - a Cat is a specialised type of Animal.   However, Wang is simply a name of particular individuals, not some specialised type of person.

Comment: @Peter I do this because different has different ways to haveFun(). Consider Wang as a Hero in some games.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.     Heroism is a situational attribute (e.g. bravery in the face of fire, being presented awards or privileges for that bravery, etc), not something that defines a different subclass of person.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your advice. I should put name as a field in Person ,and change Wang to Developer and that makes more sense.  But if each developer has a unique way to haveFun(), then I think I still need to create classes like Dave and Cally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little awkward to use double dispatch/visitor here since your code provided for `Floor` already stores `Base*` and there's only one inheritance hierarchy. The type info is already kind of lost at this point without quite an intrusive design change.

Whatever you use, typically you need some form of branching based on the actual sub-type. It might be a second virtual dispatch, it might be `if/else` statements looking at type information, it might be attempts at `dynamic_casts` and either catching a `bad_cast` (for references) or checking the result against `nullptr` for pointers.

In your case, I would actually suggest something like this if you want to avoid `dynamic_cast`/RTTI and keep the code mostly as-is:

```
class Animal;
class Person;

class Base{
public:
    ...
    virtual Person* person() {return nullptr;}
    virtual Animal* animal() {return nullptr;}
    ...
}

class Person: public Base{
public:
    ...
    Person* person() override {return this;}
    ...
}

class Animal: public Base{
public:
    ...
    Animal* animal() override {return this;}
    ...
}
```

This couples `Person/Animal` to `Base` but only at a symbol kind of level. `Base` can still be decoupled from `Person/Animal` in every other way (including compile-time header dependencies).

It does mean you have to add code to `Base` for each sub-type you want to handle separately, but you typically need to do that anyway somewhere no matter what you use (visitor included).

```
class Floor{
    Base *bs;
public:
    void haveFun(){ 
      // If `bs` is a person, invoke `haveFun`.
      Person* person = bs->person();
      if (person)
          person->haveFun();
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that each new sub-type you add that you want to handle on a sub-type level through a pointer to `Base*` requires adding new functions to `Base` (though adding new functions to `Base` isn't very vulnerable to the fragile base class syndrome). The upside is that you can, say, change the interface of `Person` or `Animal` considerably and not have to update `Base`. It is reasonably easy to extend against new requirements, and avoids the down cast (which arguably might be easier to misuse). This makes the design a bit more explicit about what is legit behavior than casting between types, and avoids the potential RTTI requirement (if that is a concern for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid downcasting (which is a reasonable thing to want, although it's not strictly necessary since dynamic_cast<> will provide safe downcasting), you have two options:

1) Declare all of the methods you might want to call in the base class, as virtual methods.  Define base-class implementations of those methods that just do nothing or return an error code (or similar), so that when you call those methods on objects of inappropriate types, nothing harmful will happen.

or

2) Keep multiple pointers in your Floor class; one for each type of object that you might want to hold there.  That way when you e.g. want to call haveFun(), you know that your Person object is accessible via the (Person *) pointer and not the (Animal *) pointer.  If you want to enforce the only-one-object-per-Floor constraint, be sure to clear the Animal pointer when setting the Person pointer, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have another class between Person and Wang. For example, GoodPerson, which has a field (moneyDonate : int) and a method (getMoneyDonate() : int). Can I just put a virtual  getMoneyDonated():int in the base class?

Comment: Sure; you could have the base-class method just return 0 or something. Of course the eventual downside to this is that your base class can start to get very cluttered with lots of methods, but it will work.